# Using semicolon ';' to combine commands gives different output then using pipe '|'

Tags: unix

I know saying this may have me looked down upon, but this question is for homework from my UNIX class. While in my home directory, I am supposed to display all files in the `/dev` directory that begin with `"sda"`. I can easily accomplish this by typing the command

```
ls /dev | grep ^sda
```

which results in the desired output of `"sda, sda1, sda2, ..."`.

Now I am trying to replicate this output without using pipe, so I type the command

```
ls /dev ; grep ^sda
```

which outputs every file in the directory instead of only the ones that start with `sda`.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You will also notice, that after `grep ^sda` the prompt does not return, because grep is waiting for standard input.

Answer (score 5):

Semicolons are command separators. That means that each command is run, one before the next, and the output goes to the terminal. There are other command separators like && and ||. These will only run the next command in the sequence if the first succeeds (&&) or fails (||).

The pipe operator, on the other hand, connects the output of one command to the input of another. In your example, the output of `ls` (a list of files) is provided as input to `grep`. The two commanda are actually running at the same time, with output from the first immediately going in as input to the second.

You get different results, then, because you are doing fundamentally different things.

```
ls /dev | grep ^sda
```

Takes the output of ls and only returns entries that start with "sda". Meanwhile,

```
ls /dev ; grep ^sda
```

Runs ls to completion, listing all files in /dev. And then it runs grep. Grep actually waits for you to type something since it has nothing connected to its input stream.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So is there another way to get the desired output without using pipe? My teacher said to not use the pipe operator for this question.

Comment: @Bahnu Yes. You can use globbing, as in Jens's answer (`ls /dev/sda*`). Or you can do weird stuff like `grep ^sda < <(ls /dev)`. Your instructor might find the latter to be a cheeky way to skirt the rules.

Comment: I haven't used stackoverflow in a while and even then rarely used it so I'm not sure if this is the correct place to comment this, but thank you for your help everyone! My question has been solved.

Comment: @Bahnu That's great! You should upvote my question if it's helpful and click the little checkmark next to the votes to indicate that it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The command to list all files in `/dev` starting with `sda` without a  pipe and grep is

```
ls /dev/sda*
```

Here the asterisk is a shell globbing character meaning *any sequence of characters, including none*. It might output, for example,

```
/dev/sda   /dev/sda1   /dev/sda2
```

There are other ways to glob filenames in the shell, namely

- `?` representing exactly one character
- `[a-z]` representing ranges of a single character

Try

```
ls /dev/sda[321xyz]
ls /dev/sd?
ls /dev/sd?[1-5]
ls /d[d-f]?/sd*
```